# Coupling Lua and MATLAB

Tags: matlab, lua, scientific-computing

I am in the situation where I have a part of the codebase written in MATLAB and another part in Lua (which is used for scripting of a 3rd party program). As of now the exchange of data between them is makeshift, using the file I/O system. This evolved to be a substantial part of the code, even though that wasn't really planned.

The program is structured in a way, that some Lua scripts are run, then some MATLAB evaluation is done based on which some more Lua is run and so on. It handles simulations and evaluations (scientific code) and creates new simulations based on that. It handles thousands of files and sims.

To streamline the process I started looking into possibilities to change the data I/O and make easy calls from one to another.

I wanted to hear some opinions on how to solve the problem, the optimal solution would be one where I could call everything from MATLAB or Lua, and organize the large datasets in a more consistent and accessible way.

*Solutions:*

1. Use the Lua C API to create bindings for the Lua modules, and to add this to MATLAB as a C-Library. In this way I should hopefully be able to achieve my goals and reduce the system complexity.
2. Some smarter data format for the exchange of datasets (HDF?), and some functions which read the needed workspace variables. This way the parts of the program remain independent, but the data exchange gets solved.
3. Create wrappers for Lua/MATLAB functions, so they can be called more easily. Data exchange could be done through the return parameters of the functions.
4. Suggestions?

Comment: You can use the MATLAB MEX API to pass data from MATLAB to C/C++ and vice-versa, then do whatever with that.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest 1 or if you aren't adverse to spending a lot of money, use [MATLAB coder](https://www.mathworks.com/products/matlab-coder/) to generate C functions from the MATLAB side of the analysis, compile the generated code as a shared library, import the library with the LuaJIT FFI, and run everything from Lua. With this solution you would not have to change any of the MATLAB code and not much of the Lua code thanks to the LuaJIT's semantics regarding array indexing. Solution 1 is free, but it is not as efficient because of the constant marshaling between the two languages' data structures. It would also be a lot of work writing the interface. But either solution would be more efficient than file I/O.

As a easy performance boost, have you tried keeping the files in memory using a RAMdisk or tmpfs?